How to upgrade .NET framework version for .wixproj in VS
I have a solution that includes a single .wixproj and I'm trying to upgrade its .NET Framewrok.
Usually, for cs projects I right click the project, choose properties then change the .NET target framework. I don't have that option in the properties for the .wixproj.
I've downloaded WiX v3 - Visual Studio 2019 Extension to load the project, but that didn't help me for the upgrade.
I can't find any guidence on the internet, the only documentation I found on wixtoolset website is How To: Check for .NET Framework Versions and in one of its steps I need to link WixNetFxExtension.dll to my project as a reference, but I don't know where to find the WixNetFxExtension.dll

Commonly, the WiX toolset contains WixNetFxExtension.dll.  You can redownload the latest version of the WiX toolset and install it, searching WixNetFxExtension.dll in it.

Wix project  use XML to generate msi database. The project itself does not need to set the Framework version.
DLL location is
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset <version>\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll"

